# Dropdown Navbar works in bootply, not browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Can someone help me out with this?  The dropdown menu works if I copy and paste into Bootply but does not function in Chrome... Here is the bootply:

http://bootply.com/73407

The only difference between the two is the area before the body tag begins (not needed for bootply). I'll post it below.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hulman Street Wesleyan Church - About Us</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="keywords" content="enter, comma separated, keywords, here">
<meta name="description" content="Enter a brief description of your website here">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600|Droid+Sans|Cabin:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I do call the java-scripts at the bottom of the page, apparently it is supposed to load faster.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your paths are correct? Are the other styles being applied?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are called correctly with the right file path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [Bootstrap JavaScript](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns) and make sure your CSS paths are correct.

Comment: I call the javascripts at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Is there a testing page we could see?